# How do I preprocess this data for training?

Tags: python, onnx

I have this code (onnx), but in the original code, they use it with only the close prices, and I want to input the ohlc. How to I preprocess this data?

This is the data:

```
             time     open     high      low    close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
0      1624053600  1.18709  1.18774  1.18660  1.18673         2428      14            0
1      1624057200  1.18671  1.18691  1.18561  1.18613         1255      14            0
2      1624233600  1.18560  1.18651  1.18555  1.18632          335      18            0
3      1624237200  1.18631  1.18735  1.18618  1.18712          932      16            0
4      1624240800  1.18712  1.18748  1.18683  1.18700          823      15            0
...           ...      ...      ...      ...      ...          ...     ...          ...
11967  1684519200  1.07852  1.08258  1.07815  1.08184        11352      14            0
11968  1684522800  1.08182  1.08242  1.08108  1.08200         4143      14            0
11969  1684526400  1.08201  1.08280  1.08173  1.08190         2279      14            0
11970  1684530000  1.08190  1.08196  1.08072  1.08076         2052      14            0
11971  1684533600  1.08076  1.08085  1.07971  1.08053         1656      14            0
```

This is what I tried (here the original code only used the close):

```
    data['open'] = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df.open.values.reshape(-1,1))
    data['high'] = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df.high.values.reshape(-1,1))
    data['low'] = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df.low.values.reshape(-1,1))
    data['close'] = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df['close'].values.reshape(-1,1))
    data = data[['open','high','low','close']].values
```

but when setting the training size:

```
training_size = int(len(data)*0.80) 
    print("Training_size:",training_size)
    train_data_initial = data[0:training_size,:]
    test_data_initial = data[training_size:,:1]
```

.....

and when training, an error appears:

```
        # split into samples
    time_step = inp_history_size
    x_train, y_train = split_sequence(train_data_initial, time_step)
    x_test, y_test = split_sequence(test_data_initial, time_step)

    # reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features] which is required for LSTM
    x_train =x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1],1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0],x_test.shape[1],1)
```

Error:

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 24855600 into shape (8877,700,1)

I'm not sure of what is happening here... what is 24855600? Why that big number? And how can I reshape this?